# Inferring type on interface using provided type mapping

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that has "type" and "id" properties, and the type of the id property is dependent on the value of "type".

```
interface MyInterface<T extends keyof any, IDMAP extends TypeMap<T>> {
    type: T;
    id: IDMAP[T];
}
```

The problem is that the type of "id" doesn't get inferred when I check the value of "type".

I don't understand why. Is this a bug? What can I change to make this kind of check work?

```
const testMethod = (
    action: MyInterface<MyEnum, EnumTypeMap>,
) => {
    if (action.type === MyEnum.ONLY_NUMBER) {
        // Why is this not inferred to be number?
        testInferrence(action.id);
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/PTAiFEDEEkDloCrQPKwMoCgAuBPADgKYAEC+BAsgIZ4A8CRBAHlgQHYAmAzkQNYE4B7AGZFKrHAD4iAXiIBvDESVEA2gGkiAS1YkAugC5R4gNwYAvqYzaWAJyGUAxsXI5orW-ad0GzNl178wkY4ADRE0KDkAIIACj4sHNykhFS0CBJSCspEuISGCKbZmuyGEdExKgi6pmYYGGwArgC2RC7grM3yisqoADIAmgD6aAgASnAA4jJEAOR9QyPjsBMzId1K84OwAKrkAELgo9NzsANbuwejq+Z1ucTtzckU1NNZyiptHU0AdJuLkwYiJwsDZtABzQrvT7NX6nIY7faHQFfABGBBsNUsGBAJHAI0wDgErGBOQIwPIBCwAAsBOxpgAKdaiBxYTREwwuNweRwEGjQpphB5NJ6pCRrACUMkyTM0InpjlZRO+dxk0lk-NhZwRl0lb2yShxAHUqTgtNxqZpuKwBFgtKwhOibAQ6VgBEQ0URUeiAPxM7IsYFuB02J2sJzylls1jfYriyFKWoWOqE4m2gNYIOOthOBmUQxemyS6RSFOcAQAGwI33LAjB8vFtzJWAp1Np9L1OTIHJwQs18IuhzWRRKRAAjOYG0A)

Comment: Use a discriminated union instead, or at least, change `MyInterface` to a type that generates a discriminated union.

Comment: @kelsny i dont know how to make it generate that, could you provide some example syntax? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) are used for. The problem is how to generate the discriminated union given the two types. Instead of using an interface, use a `type` definition and distribute `T` over the "original interface":

```
type MapTo<T extends keyof any, IDMAP extends TypeMap<T>> = T extends T
  ? {
      type: T;
      id: IDMAP[T];
    }
  : never;
```

`T extends T` utilizes [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of conditionals; `T extends any` could also work.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYA8MoQB7AgOwBMBnKAawhAHsAzKJPEAPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKAEs8sALoAuOgwDcnAL5zOoSFGRgYldJhz5iZCjWkgANFACSAEQQBBAAo7chEnEjr0jZmwzYn+mNxQAPwcgTw8KhBSMHLh4UIEUla2drwwYrHh8oFSeBAAbhAATkr4AK4AtmogAKJ4laE8APIAcgAyAJoA+gDKMABK5i0A4qxQAEStnb0DQ8PjJoFT3S0AqggAQjX9Y5PtK+tb-QsKnMrwUHWVrogoY1w8vAi19RUAdMszgyOSUETARREAHNMk8XpUPvsumtNttfq8AEbFOSKM4AejRsBqfR6nAAxpQ8P8oLh-ggIMAABaUAhjAAUSDxwCEhKk6k0qGeVwqZm5N3UjAAlKxmA9hLQGUyWXg3pFWCw2FzXpDpjCjsKxREIP9zHhqMUivg8RBJczCW8EoKZFAMVBKKQkCBAtlUfjCcTScBdfqioa8Mb6UhcpUkUVhSxmASiZQADYQN4xyhAhlWs6e8lUml0sWRNng96fNXbRY8BJSACMi3kqaAA)

Comment: There's also [a distributive object type](https://tsplay.dev/WvyrYm) but it does the same thing

Comment: Thanks! Both work but ill go with kelsny's because it seems more readable to me.